# Very simple Python code not working - Why is my tkinter icon not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry I know this is not very advanced at all bu i cannot figure out why this wont work

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Images tings')
root.iconbitmap("/Users/edharris/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/icon.ico")





root.mainloop()
```

It shows as a generic file con

Comment: ICO file is not supported as icon in Linux.  Use PNG and `iconphoto()` instead.

Comment: Perfect thanks guys